# Combine the aoData array from DataTables with the serliazed form

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am using jquery data table and want to combine aoData with form serialize data using jquery.

```
fnServerData: function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback,oSettings) {
                    aoData.concat( $("#frm").serializeArray());
                    console.log(aoData);
                    $.ajax( {
                                                "dataType": 'json',
                                                "type": "POST",
                                                "url": 'sSource',
                                                "data": aoData,
                                                "success": fnCallback
                                              } );
```

}

But doesn't combine and return only data table's array response.

Can you please help me out how can we do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 table_obj = $('#group-table').dataTable({
                "sAjaxSource": "URL Goes HEre",
                fnServerData: function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback,oSettings) {

                        aoData.push( $("#frm").serializeObject() );

                        console.log(aoData);
                        $.ajax( {
                                                    "dataType": 'json',
                                                    "type": "POST",
                                                    "url": sSource,
                                                    "data": aoData,
                                                    "success": fnCallback
                                                  } );

                },
                aaSorting: [[ 1, "desc" ]],
                bProcessing: true,
                bServerSide: true,
                processing : true,


                rowCallback: function(row, data, dataIndex){
                    // If row ID is in list of selected row IDs
                    if($.inArray(data[0], rows_selected) !== -1){
                       $(row).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
                       $(row).addClass('selected');
                    }
                },

                iDisplayLength: '50',
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this code and let me know

```
fnServerData: function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback,oSettings) {
                        $.ajax( {
                                  "dataType": 'json',
                                  "type": "POST",
                                  "url": 'sSource',
                                  "data": $.merge(aoData, 
                                          $("#frm").serializeArray()),
                                  "success": fnCallback
                                                  } );

                                }
```

Comment: Not combined properly...& Form data is remaining ... <pre>Array
(
    [sEcho] => 1
    [iColumns] => 2
    [sColumns] => ,
    [iDisplayStart] => 0
    [iDisplayLength] => 10
    [mDataProp_0] => 0
    [sSearch_0] => 
    [bRegex_0] => false
    [bSearchable_0] => false
    [bSortable_0] => false
    [mDataProp_1] => 1
    [sSearch_1] => 
    [bRegex_1] => false
    [bSearchable_1] => true
    [bSortable_1] => true
    [sSearch] => 
    [bRegex] => false
    [iSortCol_0] => 1
    [sSortDir_0] => desc
    [iSortingCols] => 1
    [undefined] => 
)
</pre>

Comment: Not working. getting same.. I think i have to convert all value in single object instead of merge.. like  Object { name="sSortDir_0",  value="desc"} instead of (members_status[]=[2],  source[]=[3]}

Comment: If u combine all the value into single object. The form values may confuse with same index values.

Comment: instead of doing so, It`s better to convert into json format

Comment: I tried to convert data in json format. it's converted but not combined with datatable data.

Answer (score -2):

```
table_obj = $('#group-table').dataTable({
                "sAjaxSource": "URL Goes HEre",
                fnServerData: function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback,oSettings) {
                        $.ajax( {
                                                    "dataType": 'json',
                                                    "type": "POST",
                                                    "url": sSource,
                                                    "data": $.merge(aoData, $("#frm").serializeArray()),
                                                    "success": fnCallback
                                                  } );

                },
                aaSorting: [[ 1, "desc" ]],
                bProcessing: true,
                bServerSide: true,
                processing : true,


                rowCallback: function(row, data, dataIndex){
                    // If row ID is in list of selected row IDs
                    if($.inArray(data[0], rows_selected) !== -1){
                       $(row).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
                       $(row).addClass('selected');
                    }
                },

                iDisplayLength: '50',
            });
```

Comment: You should not copy paste other peoples answers.